# For same properties Intellij shows that one of them is unused

Tags: java, intellij-idea, properties, unused-variables

I have 2 properties identically used, but one of them is shown as unused. I cannot find any dependencies or rules, why I have half of properties inspected by Intellij Ultimate that way.

Any thoughts? :)

[Unused property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zv9l.png)

["Unused" property usages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXRcS.png)

[Where it used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF1oO.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: @y.bedrov yes it didn't help. Also I tried creating new properties, coping from other files\projects, every time I have different behavior. I work in 4 module big project with Spring and Tapestry, if it changes something.

Comment: Is it possibel to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?